# After a successful run test class the main class coverage is showing none

Tags: apex, unit-test

[image]Hello Techies,
I have a wired issue After a Successful run test class the main class coverage is showing none.
Below is the screenshot.
If anyone also faces this issue then please let me know.

[image]

Comment: You need to select your class name from the Overal Code Coverage section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that you just need to clear out some old data. Take the following steps.

First, go to Setup > Custom Code > Apex Test Execution > View Test History, and click on Clear Test Data.

Next, go to Setup > Custom Code > Apex Classes, and click on Compile All Classes. Wait for this to finish.

After that, go back to Setup > Custom Code > Apex Test Execution > Options, and make sure that **Store Only Aggregated Code Coverage** is *not* checked.

Finally, go back to the Developer Console, reload (F5), and then run your test(s) again. After this, you should be able to see your code coverage.

Note that this is basically a glitched state, it doesn't happen often, but when it does, you can follow these steps to restore normal functionality.